# handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I tried to include the redux form inside my stepper.
- so I followed this tutorial and used async form https://redux-form.com/8.0.4/docs/gettingstarted.md/
- in their demo its working fine.
- but when I hit sign up button I am facing an error  handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop.
- so I debugged all the files by putting console.
- when I hit submit none of my consoles are printing.
- will there be problem due to handleSubmit.
- can you tell me how to fix it  so that in future I will fix it myself.
- providing my sandbox and code snippet below.
  https://codesandbox.io/s/98qjwrrklr

```or-tag-here
const AsyncValidationForm = props => {
  console.log("AsyncValidationForm ---->");

  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field
        name="username"
        type="text"
        component={renderField}
        label="Username"
      />
      <Field
        name="password"
        type="password"
        component={renderField}
        label="Password"
      />
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>
          Sign Up
        </button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>
          Clear Values
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

You have to pass an onSubmit parameter to the component that has de reduxForm HOC:

```js
  <AsyncValidationForm onSubmit={values => { console.log(values) }} />
```

2)
You are not creating the store correctly because the store needs a form field like the example:

```
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from 'redux-form';
const reducer = combineReducers({
  form: reduxFormReducer, // mounted under "form"
});
```

but you are defining the store as below:

```
const reducer = () => ({});
const store = createStore(reducer);
```

You can simply import store from your store.js file in the index.js:

```
import store from './store';
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply...so confusing...can you update in sandbox directly

Comment: Yes, no problem. I forked your example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/8499pm0no9

And I recommend you delete the unused files with repeated names because is a little confusing.

Comment: can you give the comments in the code...its so hard to understand...here I am seeing alert when I click submit button but how come its not happening in ours https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/asyncvalidation/

Comment: still I didnt see alert when I hit signup I think problem is due to this method showResults in showResults.js and I am seeing an error Error: Promise did not implement oncancel

Comment: I updated my fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/8499pm0no9, please read the code carefully :) 

In steps/Step1.js, where you use the AsyncValidationForm Component, I am passing a property onSubmit to the Component, [as the documentation says](https://redux-form.com/8.0.4/docs/gettingstarted.md/): The submitted data is passed as JSON object to your onSubmit function. Let's console.log it out:

Comment: I went through the documentation but still didnt understand...can you explain in detail it will be very helpful for me

Comment: The function reduxForm converts a React Component in a Redux Form Component. The documentation explains how to use this function and how you have to pass the property "onSubmit" to the Redux Form Component. Inside the Redux Form Component, you have to use handleSubmit to prevent the default behaviour and to left that redux-form module makes his magic. The onSubmit property is documented in [the reduxForm API](https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/).

I think that you should start with [a simpler example](https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/simple/) to understand redux-form ;)